# Is the Google Pixel 2 XL phone compatible with AR Core

Tags: android-augmented-reality, arcore

Could someone having access to the latest Google Pixel 2 (XL) phone please confirm whether the phone is compatible with AR Core?

## EDIT

At the time I asked the question there was no information on whether or not Pixel 2 supported ARCore but since then they updated the website with the following information:

Google Pixel, Pixel XL, Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL

And I got a Pixel 2 in my hand and can confirm I got it working.

Comment: Huuu just a comment... This is a valid question and one that relates to programming and HW compatibility. Furthermore the AR Core website itself refers to stack overflow as a place where questions related to AR Core can be asked. If you don't like the question just ignore but don't down vote. This is question is not only valid but also useful to people ,...

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of supported devices here updated regularly
[Supported Devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/)